# How can I set region format in XCTest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, xctest

I want to test my code by changing region formats in (Settings > General > Language & Region) to different regions like UK, Japan etc. How can I do so programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a specific scheme for your different tests. For each scheme, add an "Argument Passed on Launch" like `-AppleLocale en_US`.

[image: Xcode Scheme screenshot]

Comment: @shalzangel let me know if that seem to fix your issue.

Comment: This seems to fix it in my case. I have to check a compound string including the formatted date which gives different values if I run it in the "en_us" simulator than I receive on the "en" device

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that there is currently any way to programmatically set the language for the entire phone. You will probably have to do it manually every time through the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Hugues BR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276355)'s answer ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34094152/1071320)): In newer versions of Xcode, we can change the App Language and App Region for the tests in a given Scheme from the System Language and System Region to a language and region of our choosing. See screenshot below.

[image: Xcode Scheme screenshot]